# Condense initials/abbreviations with regex (or something else?)

Tags: .net, regex

I'm implementing a fuzzy lookup tool, and I think I can improve results by collapsing separate initials into a single token, e.g. "A B C Warehouse" becomes just two tokens: "ABC" and "Warehouse".

In other words, it would need to remove spaces (or periods) between all consecutive pairs of *isolated* alphanumerics. So these would condense...

- A B C Warehouse
- A.B.C. Warehouse

But these would not...

- AB C Warehouse
- A BC Warehouse

My first hunch was to use a regex replacement, which naturally means now I have two problems instead of one. This is roughly what I tried, which doesn't work. This is T-SQL code calling a function that's just a wrapper to .Net's Regex methods.

It will condense the "A B" into "AB", which then disqualifies the "C" from being condensed into the pair "AB", resulting in "AB C Warehouse". (At least I think that's what's happening; I'm not an expert on regex internals.)

```
master.dbo.RegexReplace(
    'A B C Warehouse',
    '(?<c1>(^|[^a-z0-9])[a-z0-9])[ \.](?<c2>[a-z0-9]([^a-z0-9]|$))',
    '${c1}${c2}',
    0 /*Case-sensitivity flag*/
)
```

Should I even do this sort of thing with a regex, or would it make a lot more sense to just write a routine that does a stateful scan of the input string and cleans it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this replace:

```
find: (?<=\b[A-Z])[ .](?=[A-Z]\b)
replacement is an empty string.
```

explanations:

The pattern search space or dot preceded by a single letter and followed by a single letter. That's why it use a lookbehind `(?<=...)` and a lookahead `(?=...)` to test the presence of single letters around the dot or the space. Word boundaries `\b` are used here to ensure that letters, before and after, are alone. As lookarounds don't eat characters, the space or dot is only matched (and replaced).

Comment: All hail the regex wizard. And maybe when I'm done with this project, I can spend some time figuring out how that actually works. :)